# Python pass print statement including non strings to function

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a log class which has a function that takes input and prints it to a log file. When printing to the console an example can be:

```
print("hi",[1,2,3])
```

which results in

```
hi [1,2,3]
```

However I have a function:

```
def printLog(input):
    self.file.write('%s\n' % input)
```

However, passing this combination wouldn't work right. Is there someway I can pass "hi, [1,2,3]" as a string. This would have to convert the list to be printed exactly as it is printed in the console screen? This should deal with all data types, not just lists.

Comment: input is a builtin you should never use it as a variable name ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `file` argument of `print()` function:

```
def printLog(*inp):
    print(*inp, file=self.file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to build the string yourself. The `print` statement (and function, when available) automatically calls `str` on each of its arguments, then prints them separated (by default) by a space.

```
def printLog(*input):
    self.file.write('%s\n' % (" ".join(str(x) for x in input),))
```

Answer (score 1):

how bout

```
print("A",[1,2,3],file=self.file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I'm not mistaken, couldn't you just typecast the input into a string using str() right after you define printLog?

```
def printLog(input):
    input = str(input)
    self.file.write('%s\n' % input)
```

Comment: I think the goal is to pass multiple arguments to the `printfLog` function, just as you can with `print`.